# XlPasteType Enumeration (Excel) for Picture

Tags: excel, powershell

the link below provides the list of paste type in excel which can be used in powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype

And the reference below where the paste type for powershell was applied:

[Excel & PowerShell - PasteSpecial Failure With VLOOKUPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477528/excel-powershell-pastespecial-failure-with-vlookups)

Is there a paste type for picture? Or is there a way to paste as picture in excel using powershell?

Comment: More detail perhaps. What are you trying to paste as a picture, and from where?

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup the possible values yourself:

```
PS> Add-Type -ASSEMBLY "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" | out-null
PS> [Enum]::GetValues([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlPasteType]) |
         Select-Object @{n="Name";e={"$_"}},value__

Name                                value__
----                                -------
xlPasteValidation                         6
xlPasteAllExceptBorders                   7
xlPasteColumnWidths                       8
xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats          11
xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats            12
xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme               13
xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats      14
xlPasteValues                         -4163
xlPasteComments                       -4144
xlPasteFormulas                       -4123
xlPasteFormats                        -4122
xlPasteAll                            -4104
```

Nothing different from the table in the posted link. (just the ordering: append `|sort Name`)

Comment: Hi, the values above does not have the paste as picture. I need to be able to paste the value as Picture. In excel, there's a way to do this manually via the paste special function.

Comment: According to this [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/12/use-powershell-to-work-with-pictures-in-microsoft-excel/) inserting images is handled totally different.